# Django runserver command failed

Tags: python, django

I've been learning Python for a few months and a couple days ago i decided to learn one of Web frameworks. I found some tutorials on Django and it was looking really cool until i tried to use "runserver" command. As you can see i used the basic line "python -m django runserver manage.py" and got a lot of calls. I've just installed Django and i wasn't changing anything in it's scripts. I only started by creating a new project that worked perfectly with "python -m django startproject djangoLearn". Do you have any thoughts on how can i fix this problem? This problem prevents me from further learning beacuse i can't see my own project :((
Thanks in advance. Hope y'all have a great day.
Calls that i get while trying to run server:

```
D:\Projects\djangoLearn>python -m django runserver manage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main 
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
File "C:\Users\norml\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Why are you using `python -m django runserver manage.py`? Try just doing `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: set debug 1 in setting file, like this, and then try: `DEBUG = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=1))`

Comment: @simon_736, and share **manage.py** code in question.

Comment: @Chris I didnt know it would be this easy. I've been using `python -m django runserver manage.py` because i used different commands like `python -m django startproject djangoLearn` before and i thought that changing the last two arguments will be enough. Thanks for help and have a nice day :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your virtualenv is activated ??
use this to create project `django-admin startproject projectname .` take note of the period it works without the period though.

use `python manage.py startapp appname` to create an app
don't forget to register the app in INSTALLED_APP

i think the code you want to use is `python manage.py runserver`

but if you use python3 use `python3 manage.py runserver` just use whatever you use to start your python before `manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

you should first activate your virtual environment. with a command like this in linux:

```
source "path-to-activate-file"
```

and command like this in windows:

```
\pathto\env\Scripts\activate
```